# How to add extra item attribute shopping cart Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, shopping-cart

I have configurable products in the shopping cart but i want to add one column with stock item the products by sizes

i have an observer

```
 <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
     <observers>
        <shopping_cart>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>Myspace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
           <method>addExtraItemShoppingCart</method>
         </shopping_cart>
     </observers>
 </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>





public function addExtraItemShoppingCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();

    foreach ($cartItems as $item){
        $productType = $item->getProduct()->getTypeId();
        if($productType!='configurable'){
            //Mage::log($item->getSku(), null, 'shoppingCartB2B.log',true);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
            $size = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('talla')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            $item->setData('talla', $item->getId())->save();
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}
```

and in the file
`app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

`$_item->getData('talla');`

print talla, but does not work.

if someone can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem :) 
this is a solution.
In the file

app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

add

```
$product_child = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());

$product_hild =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->loadByAttribute('sku',$product_child['simple_sku']);
```